# Action bar custom view incorrect size

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I customized the `ActionBar` by inflating a custom view (the orange background is custom view).

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar, null);
getActionBar().setCustomView(v);
```

[image]

My problem is that the custom view width doesn't fill the whole space of action bar, since I want the blue tiny bar to appear on top of the app (full width). Also I want the menu items to stay there on top of custom view.

Although I set the custom view width and height to `fill_parent` and `match_parent`, but both height and width of the custom view are incorrect.

I don't want to use ActionBarSherlock.

**Update**

I styled the caption using @Malachiasz answer, but how can I add the blue bar above the action bar?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use an image with top border in blue color and set it as background to your actionbar?

Comment: I need to use custom view because of custom fonts in title.

Comment: the layout on which you put the action bar may not fill the screen. check the base layout.

Comment: you can still set custom fonts to your actionbar without using custom views.

Comment: @Android-Developer, it's more than just custom font, it's a CustomTypefaceSpan to have multiple fonts in the title which requires access to underlying TextView

Comment: Ok, post your custom layout so we can see what's the problem